# Given a valid combination, how to get its index in the sequence of integer partition

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

This question is extended from this [Algorithm to generate integer sets fulfills restrictions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/75144/algorithm-to-generate-integer-sets-fulfills-restrictions), in the answer I learned the formal term of this problem, and the recursive algorithm described in that answer also gives me the desired sequence - as much large numbers located in the front as possible, for example, we will get the following output for $F(7,3,4)$:

- 4>2>1
- 3>3>1
- 3>2>2

So here is the question, given a valid combination, is it possible to get its index in the result set without generating the whole result set and searching for it?

Comment: Yes, using the recursive formula. This is similar to mapping a $k$-subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ into a number in the range $0,\ldots,\binom{n}{k}-1$, which has been described a few times on this site.

Comment: Hi Yuval, thanks for your comment, can you please give me the link to one of those questions?

Comment: See here: https://computationalcombinatorics.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/ranking-and-unranking-of-combinations-and-permutations/.

Comment: Hi Yuval, can you please elaborate because I still have trouble in figuring it out.

Comment: As the link shows, ranking and unranking (finding the index given the set and vice versa) essentially reduce to calculating how many solutions there are with given prefix. So, how many solutions there are in total, how many begin with $a$, how many begin with $a>b$, and so on. If you know how to calculate these (switching prefix with suffix it that problem is easier), then you can rank and unrank. See if you understand how this works for $k$-subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, which you can think of as 0/1 vectors of length $n$ containing exactly $k$ ones.

Comment: I think I understand it a little bit more, so it's like regenerating the whole sequence, but instead of really doing it, we sum the count for each leading part and remove the leading part in our specific permutation and do it recursively. Things become different from here, unlike ranking unranking permutation of a given combination, we still need to know the total number of partitions with such a leading part in our case, which is unknown for me yet. I mean there could be a simple formula for this just I didn't know. Hope I made myself clear. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Right, you need to find a way to count partitions with a leading (or trailing) part. This can probably be done using generating functions (or dynamic programming).

Answer (score 1):

This is called **ranking combinatiorial objects**, in this case **combinations**. Ranking and unranking algorithms exist for various simple combinatorial objects and even a general ranking algorithm exists for arbitrary combinatorial objects given that computing the number of objects matching certain criteria is feasible and there is a total ordering (eg lexicographic ordering).

For combinations, a reference is [Algorithms for Unranking Combinations and Other Related Choice Functions, Zbigniew Kokosinski 1995](http://riad.pk.edu.pl/~zk/pubs/95-1-006.pdf)

Assuming a lexicographic ordering among combinations of $K$ from $N$ the following algorithm can be used (which runs in $O(K)$ time assuming binomial computations are cheap):

Assuming the combination is given as an array (`item`) of length $K$ and where

$$item[0]<item[1]<\dots<item[K-1]$$

and each $0 \leq item[i] \leq N-1$

(If you want the combination in reverse order simply change the algorithm below to match in reverse order and skip last step. Also since your combinations take values between $1$ and $N$ you might want to subtract $1$ from below algorithms, where $item[i]$ is used)

$index = 0$

for $i=1$ to $K$:

____ $c = N-1-item[i-1]$

____ $j = K+1-i$

____ if $j \leq c$ then $index \leftarrow index+\binom{c}{j}$

Finally: $index \leftarrow \binom{N}{K}-1-index$

**Note:** The algorithm above can be modified to rank combinations with repeated/duplicate elements. Ie

$$item[0] \leq item[1] \leq \dots \leq item[K-1]$$

One needs to replace the counts used to represent combinations with repeated elements instead of binomials which count combinations with unique elements.

$index = 0$

$N \leftarrow N+K-1$

for $i=1$ to $K$:

____ $c = N-1-item[i-1]-i+1$

____ $j = K+1-i$

____ if $j \leq c$ then $index \leftarrow index+\binom{c}{j}$

Finally: $index \leftarrow \binom{N}{K}-1-index$

In essense ranking combinations is a bijection from $N,K$ combinations to natural numbers $0 \dots \binom{N}{K}-1$. This defines a [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system).

Algorithms above are modified to match my use case (for my combinatorics library [Abacus](https://foo123.github.io/examples/abacus/)) where combinations take values $0 \dots N-1$ and are non-decreasing. For your use case you can modify them to match wikipedia article.